# What does this query mean...?

Tags: sql, database

```
declare @memberid int
declare @uid int

select memberid, uid into #temp from member

While (Select Count(*) From #Temp) > 0
Begin
    select top 1 @memberid= memberid, @uid=uid from #temp
    update savingdetail set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2063_2064 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2064_2065 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2065_2066 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2066_2067 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2067_2068 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    delete from #temp where memberid=@memberid
End

drop table #temp
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is basically updating the `UId` of `SAVING_DETAILS` tables for each member. Follow comments below;

```
select memberid, uid into #temp from member --> populate a temporary table with members details

While (Select Count(*) From #Temp) > 0  --> Loop for each record in the temp table
Begin
    select top 1 @memberid= memberid, @uid=uid from #temp  --> Select the top most record from the temp table
    update savingdetail set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid  --> Update the UId of the savingdetail table with the one of the temp table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ----> Updating the UId of the savingdetail tables with the one of the temp table
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2063_2064 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2064_2065 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2065_2066 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2066_2067 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
    update SAVINGDETAIL_2067_2068 set uid=@uid where memberid=@memberid
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    delete from #temp where memberid=@memberid  --> Delete the record already updated from the temp table
End

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is rather inefficiently updating the `uid`s from 6 tables to match the `uid`s in the `member` table.  It loads the table to be updated into a temporary table, and then updates the records one at a time.

It would more typically be written using six update statements, one for each table.  The first might look like:

```
update sv
    set sv.uid = m.uid
    from member m join
         savingdetail sv
         on m.memberid = sv.memberid;
```